# C# UWP Animate Canvas position

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, win-universal-app

I am creating many of the controls in my Universal Windows Platform App dynamically at run time as a result of data retrieved.

I would like to animate the position of a Canvas such that it moves in from one side then out to the other side when done. Can anyone point me in the correct direction to achieve this using just C# code and not XAML.

I have tried using doubleanimation but cant see how to tie this to the animation of my canvas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read through [How to ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Seems you've asked the same question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/79a6b826-6101-4bb0-aa86-2e55d91bcc6d/). I agree with  
Breeze Liu. His answer should solve your problem.